# Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured trying to use google speech API

Tags: java, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to go through google cloud speech API to see how accurate they convert Korean to text.

My operating system is Windwos10, using Eclipse and Maven. I am now trying to build Maven. However I am keep getting same error. I googled it but I have no idea.

Below is log from Eclipse.

```
Exception in thread "grpc-default-executor-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured.
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.selectApplicationProtocolConfig(GrpcSslContexts.java:153)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:130)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:119)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:90)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.createProtocolNegotiator(NettyChannelBuilder.java:265)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory.newClientTransport(NettyChannelBuilder.java:324)
    at io.grpc.internal.CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.newClientTransport(CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.java:62)
    at io.grpc.internal.TransportSet.startNewTransport(TransportSet.java:215)
    at io.grpc.internal.TransportSet.obtainActiveTransport(TransportSet.java:192)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$3.getTransport(ManagedChannelImpl.java:651)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$3.getTransport(ManagedChannelImpl.java:592)
    at io.grpc.DummyLoadBalancerFactory$DummyLoadBalancer$1.get(DummyLoadBalancerFactory.java:135)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientTransport$2.run(DelayedClientTransport.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
4월 12, 2017 10:19:38 오전 io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl <init>
정보: [ManagedChannelImpl@70e38ce1] Created with target speech.googleapis.com:443
Exception in thread "grpc-default-executor-4" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured.
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.selectApplicationProtocolConfig(GrpcSslContexts.java:153)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:130)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:119)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:90)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.createProtocolNegotiator(NettyChannelBuilder.java:265)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory.newClientTransport(NettyChannelBuilder.java:324)
    at io.grpc.internal.CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.newClientTransport(CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.java:62)
    at io.grpc.internal.TransportSet.startNewTransport(TransportSet.java:215)
    at io.grpc.internal.TransportSet.obtainActiveTransport(TransportSet.java:192)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$3.getTransport(ManagedChannelImpl.java:651)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$3.getTransport(ManagedChannelImpl.java:592)
    at io.grpc.DummyLoadBalancerFactory$DummyLoadBalancer$1.get(DummyLoadBalancerFactory.java:135)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientTransport$2.run(DelayedClientTransport.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 127.968 sec <<< FAILURE!
test16KHzAudio(googlecloudstt.StreamingRecognizeClientTest)  Time elapsed: 64.603 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Not true that <""> contains <"how old is the Brooklyn Bridge">
    at googlecloudstt.StreamingRecognizeClientTest.test16KHzAudio(StreamingRecognizeClientTest.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Not true that <""> contains <"how old is the Brooklyn Bridge">
    at com.google.common.truth.FailureStrategy.fail(FailureStrategy.java:28)
    at com.google.common.truth.FailureStrategy.fail(FailureStrategy.java:22)
    at com.google.common.truth.Subject.failComparingToStrings(Subject.java:348)
    at com.google.common.truth.Subject.fail(Subject.java:325)
    at com.google.common.truth.StringSubject.contains(StringSubject.java:126)
    ... 32 more

test32KHzAudio(googlecloudstt.StreamingRecognizeClientTest)  Time elapsed: 63.345 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Not true that <""> contains <"how old is the Brooklyn Bridge">
    at googlecloudstt.StreamingRecognizeClientTest.test32KHzAudio(StreamingRecognizeClientTest.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Not true that <""> contains <"how old is the Brooklyn Bridge">
    at com.google.common.truth.FailureStrategy.fail(FailureStrategy.java:28)
    at com.google.common.truth.FailureStrategy.fail(FailureStrategy.java:22)
    at com.google.common.truth.Subject.failComparingToStrings(Subject.java:348)
    at com.google.common.truth.Subject.fail(Subject.java:325)
    at com.google.common.truth.StringSubject.contains(StringSubject.java:126)
    ... 32 more


Results :

Failed tests:   test16KHzAudio(googlecloudstt.StreamingRecognizeClientTest): Not true that <""> contains <"how old is the Brooklyn Bridge">
  test32KHzAudio(googlecloudstt.StreamingRecognizeClientTest): Not true that <""> contains <"how old is the Brooklyn Bridge">

Tests run: 5, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031329/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-jetty-alpn-npn-has-not-been-properly-configu

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but it looks like this happens when Jetty is trying to load a class that is not in your bootclasspath.  Take a look at this site:

https://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/alpn-chapter.html

It indicates you need to start the JVM as such:

> java -Xbootclasspath/p:<path_to_alpn_boot_jar> ...